# VESA: SUMO driver instead of being the ones I installed (fgrlx-updates) ubuntu 13.04 64-bit IGP (HD 6xxxG)

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

Hello everyone and thank the community for providing support for linux newbie like me.
I'll go with a problem that I face to:

When you get to the menu with my video card details show: VESA: SUMO driver instead of being the ones I installed (fgrlx-updates) or to show what card is installed on the laptop... product: Sumo [Radeon HD 6380G]

P.S. this is my first post here, so if the problem is already solved sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I was completely overloaded with information and pretty lost, which is why I have not been careful.

Anyway who are still in difficulty here is the answer:

[what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/286775#286775)